# Tab Bar Item hidden behind tableview / not being shown?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have an empty view with a tab bar pictured below, when i load a routine a table appears containing the contents, however it seems to overlay the tab bar killing off app navigation. Its not sized in the storyboard to overlay it and its constraint locked to not do so, so im unsure why this is happening, pics of the issue and VC's code below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

VC Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RoutineController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - DECLARATIONS

    @IBAction func unwindToRoutine(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
    @IBOutlet weak var daysRoutineTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var columnHeaderBanner: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var todaysRoutineNavBar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var addTOdaysRoutineLabel: UILabel!

    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let segueEditUserExerciseViewController = "editExerciseInRoutineSegue"

    //This is the selected routine passed from the previous VC
    var selectedroutine : UserRoutine?

    // MARK: - VIEWDIDLOAD

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        daysRoutineTable.delegate = self
        daysRoutineTable.dataSource = self

        view.backgroundColor = (UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite())

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        todaysRoutineNavBar.topItem?.title = dateStr + " Routine"
    }

    // MARK: - VIEWDIDAPPEAR

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.daysRoutineTable.reloadData()
        self.updateView()
    }

    // MARK: - TABLE UPDATE COMPONENTS

    private func setupView() {
        updateView()
    }

    // MARK: - TABLE SETUP

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = self.selectedroutine?.userexercises?.count
        {
            print("exercises: \(count)")
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? TodaysRoutineTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        configure(cell, at: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - VIEW CONTROLER ELEMENTS VISIBILITY CONTROL

    fileprivate func updateView() {
        var hasUserExercises = false
        if let UserExercise = self.selectedroutine?.userexercises {
            hasUserExercises = UserExercise.count > 0
        }

        addTOdaysRoutineLabel.isHidden = hasUserExercises
        columnHeaderBanner.isHidden = !hasUserExercises
        daysRoutineTable.isHidden = !hasUserExercises
    }

    // MARK: - SETTING DATA FOR A TABLE CELL

    func configure(_ cell: TodaysRoutineTableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let userExercise = selectedroutine?.userexercises?.allObjects[indexPath.row]
        {
            print("\((userExercise as! UserExercise).name)")
        cell.todaysExerciseNameLabel.text = (userExercise as! UserExercise).name
        cell.todaysExerciseRepsLabel.text = String((userExercise as! UserExercise).reps)
        cell.todaysExerciseSetsLabel.text = String((userExercise as! UserExercise).sets)
        cell.todaysExerciseWeightLabel.text = String((userExercise as! UserExercise).weight)
        }
    }

}
```

requested table constraints

[image]

Debug hierarchy

[image]

The Segue that sends the user back to the view that looses its tab bar

```
if segue.identifier == "addToTodaySegue" {
    let indexPath = workoutTemplateTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let selectedRow = indexPath?.row
    print("selected row\(selectedRow)")
    if let selectedRoutine = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?[selectedRow!]
    {
        if let todaysRoutineController = segue.destination as? RoutineController {
            todaysRoutineController.selectedroutine = selectedRoutine
        }
    }
}
```

I also feel perhaps the viewDidAppear code may cause the issue, perhaps the super class?

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.daysRoutineTable.reloadData()
    self.updateView()
```

Updated storyboard image

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your constraints from the table view?

Comment: updated the OP with constraints

Comment: tried, does literally nothing im afraid

Comment: Did you try self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.tabBarItem ? More informations about your app flow could help.

Comment: I just tried    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.tabBarItem) if thats what you mean? It provided the same error as well, Cannot convert value of type 'UITabBarItem?' to expected argument type 'UIView'. I can provide anything else useful and add it to the OP. essentially the tab bar is there, i go to next VC, i segue back with a loaded table, the table covers the tab bar / the tab bar isnt there, not sure which of those two is the case

Comment: The problem is UITabBarItem is not an UIView subclass and can't be use with bringSubviewToFront method who take UIView argument, if you want access to your tabbar's view, you can try self.tab‌​BarController?.view instead => self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tab‌​BarController?.view) But I don't think It gonna solve your problem.

Comment: yeah thats the same conclusion i reached, just as you see the two answers below were adamant that i was the way to do it, as it isnt, i have nothing to go off for fixing it now!

Comment: Sorry didn't see the answers. You can build the app make the problem appear and back to Xcode select Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy try to play with the view and look if the tabbar is really here or not.

Comment: ah cool, ive updated the OP, looks like it isnt there?

Comment: I see, no Tabbar appear, can you tell me how view pushed ?

Comment: it segues from the next view, so to understand it as a concept, this is the daily routine view that lists exercises, you press the plus and select a routine to load, it then segues back to this view having loaded the days routine and exercises into the table, on this segue its loosing the tab controller, ill add the function above in the OP

Comment: Yes but you tell me you use xib, how did you use segue ?

Comment: ah ok, its a segue from the cell in the routine table that just unwinds to the VC with the issue, then the table loads the object passed back in viewDidAppear

Comment: Yes but you have a storyboard right ?

Comment: Just an idea, you probably tripple checked already: the type of your segue is not modal, right?

Comment: I have a story board yes, I'll check but I'm pretty sure it isn't, just away from my pc at the moment so I'll get back to you asap

Comment: You updated Storyboard looks much cleaner. Well done! There is still one Segue in the wrong direction (back to "Routine Controller") though. Delete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to embed your viewController in a `UINavigationController`.

Consider the following setup:

[image]

I suspect your setup is like the upper one:

```
TapBar -> ViewController -show segue-> ViewController
```

Which results in a hidden tapbar, like in your description:

[image]

While the bottom setup:

```
TapBar -> NavigationCntroller -rootView-> ViewController -show segue-> ViewController
```

results in:

[image]

which is what you want, how I understood.

---

**Update**

It's hard to see. The screenshot of your Storyboard is in pretty low resulution, but the segues look wrong. Double check them. A Segue of type `show (e.g push)` looks like this:

[image]

Also clear project and derived data. Segue type changes sometime are ignored until doing so.

Comment: That make sense, in view stack trace there is navigationBar, but no navigation view (called UINavigationTransitionView)

Comment: i just embedded the main VC in a nav controller and the issue still persists despite the nav controller not being the intermediary between the previous tow VC, added screenshot of the setup to OP for you

Comment: You have a segue _to_ the navigation controller. That is wrong. Delete it. To go back to a previous ViewController, you do not use Segues. You press the back button in the navigation bar or `dismiss` the viewController programatically.

Comment: And double check your segues. See bottom of my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ill give this a go, will this interfere with all my programatic segues? as i pass objects via segue and now your saying i shouldnt use them? I have updated the OP with a better more clear image of my layout, that segue back to the previous VC you can see passes the object I need back to it so its kind of essential, this setup still has the tab bar vanishing issue though when that segue triggers

Comment: Set all Segues to type "show". Nothing has to change in code. Only for the Segue _to_ the NavigationCotroller: delete it and delete code that `performSegue` on this Segue. Try first. If it works find another solution to go back to the previous viewController. For instance `dismiss`.

Comment: Is the issue that i dont use a cancel button on the nav bar to return to the previous VC as in your example? i use a segue based on the index row selected in the table to pass the object, so it doesn't actually use the nav controller anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130708/discussion-between-shallowthought-and-infernouk).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(YourTabControl)`.

Comment: just to clarify to use this id have to create an IBOutlet for the tab bar on that VC? also wouldnt this cause the table to get lost behind the forced forward tab bar?

Answer (score 0):

The previous suggestion should work. But the content at the bottom part of tableview will not be visible as the tabbar comes over it. So set the bottom constraint of tableview as the height of tabbar.

[image]

Comment: what would be the correct use of the code to select the tab bar? im trying         self.view.bringSubviewToFront(TabBarController) but thats not the correct way to select the tab bar?

Comment: Does your requirement is just to make the tabbar visible, so that it can get the click? If so, as I answered, on adjusting the constraints should give the result.